Emergent Dualism in continuation of Non-Reductive Physicalism - a mighty struggle to explain the evolution of the human mind?
Causal Closure is a metaphysical theory that states that all physical things are only caused by other physical things. It's a principle in the philosophy of mind that describes the nature of causality in the universe.
Epiphenomenalism is a philosophical position that states mental events are caused by physical events in the brain, but do not cause physical events in return
EMERGENT DUALISM - William Hasker argument from the unity of consciousness entails SUBSTANCE DUALISM. Additionally, Hasker maintains that the soul is an emergent substance, a view he calls EMERGENT DUALISM.
The main question is: how Materialism can explain the evolution of the human mind, or prove that there was no evolution, meaning that Neanderthal or Ecuadorian Amazon tribe child after birth will have the same mental capacity as any other modern human child on Earth?
William Hasker on Causal Closure and an Evolutionary Argument Against Epiphenomenalism

If premise (1) is true, that is, if causal closure obtains, then
evolutionary epistemology cannot be the explanation for human
rationality. The reasoning is simple and compelling. If causal closure
is true, then everything that happens in the brain has its complete
explanation in prior physical events, no doubt mainly earlier
brain-events. But this means that prior mental events play no role in
determining the state of a person’s brain — and therefore, they play
no role in the organism’s behavior. It follows, furthermore, that
mental events and processes are irrelevant to behavior and are thus
invisible to natural selection, which can only operate on physical
structures and physical behavior. So natural selection cannot select
for superior mental processes, nor can it play any role in explaining
the effectiveness of the mental processes we actually employ in
getting to know the world. This enormously important fact — that we
are able to reason about the world and gain know­ledge of it — is left
completely unexplained. I predict, furthermore, that within the
generally naturalistic framework that is presupposed in this
discussion, it will not be possible to find a promising alternative
explanation.


What is in question is whether an immaterial mind may be exerting a
causal influence on what happens in the brain at a micro-level.
Influence on this scale is far below the limits of our present
capacity to detect. Furthermore, we have only the vaguest notion of
what it is we would be trying to detect because we know little about
how the brain actually works at this level. I am tempted to say that
we don’t know the “machine code” for the brain, but this understates
the case. We don’t even know how the basic hard­ware (rather, wetware)
functions with regard to giving rise to particular kinds of conscious
experience.
https://biblicalscholarship.wordpress.com/2015/12/09/william-hasker-on-causal-closure-and-an-evolutionary-argument-against-epiphenomenalism/


prove that there was no evolution, meaning that Neanderthal or Ecuadorian Amazon tribe child after birth will have the same mental capacity as any other modern human child on Earth? -- Why would materialism want to prove that? This claim seems entirely disconnected from materialism, and I doubt many materialists believe it. I mean I'm sure I can find someone who believes Ecuadorian tribes are mentally equal, but they wouldn't go as far as to say ALL previous iterations of the homo genus are equal.

@TKoL - "ALL previous iterations of the homo genus" Did you read recent science news? They canceled :) "Man from Africa" in favor of genes acquired from Neanderthals.

Hasker appears to be trying to use a priori arguments to prejudge empirical questions and empirical theories. Any philosopher is welcome to do so, but no biologist will, I hope, take this kind of pseudo-scientific reasoning seriously. "Materialism" does not explain any evolution. "Materialism" is a metaphysical doctrine about which biologists don't need to have any opinion. It's particular biological theories (theories of evolution) that explain how certain organisms and species developed and adapted... (in other words: it's not philosophy that does so).

@mudskipper - "in other words: it's not philosophy that does so" - biological theories don't study evolution of human consciousness. It was always a realm of psychology and metaphysics.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance See: https://thereader.mitpress.mit.edu/how-did-consciousness-evolve-an-illustrated-guide/

This "question" needs to be recast as a question.  It would also benefit from more references, more clarity, and a less contentious framing.  The references:  William James first articulated the evolutionary test case refuting epiphenomenalism.  Karl Popper extended it to all identity theories.  William Hasker is echoing those two prior more major philosophers.    The question should be:  "what are the most effective counterarguments to the evolutionary test case from either epiphenomenalists or identity theorists".   Personally I have never encountered any, but maybe there are some.

@TKoL TheMatrixEquation-balance did not explain the evolutionary test case well enough.  Unless there is a necessary relation between brain or functions and consciousness, then the details of when and what consciousness we have will vary under evolutionary variance.  All Identity or necessity claims have failed one or more test cases (no consciousness when underlying claim holds, or is consciousness when it doesn't).  Consciousness is therefore contingent, not a necessity form either neurons, or functions.  But consciousness has all the properties of an evolutionarily optimized feature.

Consciousness has a somewhat ramshackle architecture, typical of evolved structures, but appears highly effective anyway at helping us survive, again typical.  Evolution can only do this tuning on a causal phenomenon, so consciousness is causal independent of its underlying neurology, or functions.  So far, this is just basic evolutionary/biology reasoning, and has no relevance to ontology.  The relevance comes in when epiphenomenalism claims that consciousness cannot be causal, or Identity Theory says consciousness cannot be independently causal.  Materialism should not have been mentioned.

There is also a common opinion from individual intuition, that encompasses all the literature, poetry and other casual human experiences.

@mudskipper and TKol, I did not fully articulate the test case.  The consequence of assuming either epiphenomenalism or Identity Theory and the contingent evolutionary variance we have between neurology or functions and consciousness -- is that the process of evolution in humans would lead to loss of consciousness, or inappropriate consciousness accompanying the causal events that actually determine what we do.  We know that we do causal functions and neurology unconsciously, and also have inappropriate thoughts to what we ARE doing.  Without selection pressure, these would become our minds.

I'm not really sure what you're asking. You ask "how materialism can explain", but then you present an argument against epiphenomenalism, which is (typically considered) a non-materialist / dualist position. The title mentions non-reductive physicalism, but later you mention materialism - it's not clear whether you're using those interchangeably (thereby disregarding reductive materialism), whether you're contrasting those with one another (which would imply epiphenomenalism is reductive materialism, which it most definitely isn't) or whether you're differentiating materialism and physicalism.

@NotThatGuy - Philosophy is clearly confused on this subject. Why would you expect a perfectly defined question, then?


So natural selection cannot select for superior mental processes, nor can it play any role in explaining the effectiveness of the mental processes we actually employ in getting to know the world.

This is where his argument falters. As long as the physical processes that correspond to those mental processes or are those mental processes (if you are an identity theorist) are selected for, it then stands to reason that those mental processes would be indirectly, but not directly, selected for.

"So natural selection cannot select for superior mental processes" - Obviously, it does select. But in a metaphysical way, beyond our scientific understanding.

This meta thread pointing out weird closures if you’re interested @TheMatrixEquation-balance: https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/can-someone-please-explain-to-me-why-these-sudden-closures-are-not-an-obvious-ex
